# The use of 'sort in' vs 'sort to' in programming

Tags: prepositions

In computer science, I have seen that people say that we can use an algorithm to 'sort in' ascending order. Shouldn't it be 'sort to' ascending order? Any help understanding the correct usage would be appreciated. Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: should be 'sort into'

Comment: I agree that "to" makes better sense than "in" here, and I also agree with @JonMarkPerry that "into" makes even better sense.  Nevertheless, "in" seems to be the standard usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key phrase is "in order".

> **In order**
>   1 According to a particular sequence: *list the points you intend to cover and put them in order*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-order?q=in%20order)

The word *order* is then modified by *ascending* to specify which order is intended.

Your original *we can use an algorithm to 'sort in' ascending order* should be parsed instead as *we can use (an algorithm) to [sort in (ascending order)]*.